# CSS: Text behind bootstrap 3 thumbnail

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a few issues with the thumbnails from bootstrap 3. You can see the code here: http://amazing-vt.de/#portfolio

When you hover an image, you can see the text behind this image. Now I want to center this text, but padding doesn't affect any of these links. Also I have set a height for the `<a>`with the class thumbnail. How do I have to change my css, so I don't need to set a height? How can I get the text centered? And can anyone explain me, why the image is flickering on hover?

Comment: Looking at the portfolio images the under text is already centred - on Firefox 34.

Comment: stylesheet.css line : 326
Remove padding:0px !important and then try whatever possible changes

Comment: @VipulHadiya removing the padding 0px wasn't that good. Now I have a green border around the images.

Comment: @Martin I also mean to center it vertical. Now I only centered it horizontal.

Comment: But you can manage that border anyhow. Your current HTML is not so good. li's height is 467px while actual is very small

Comment: also remove padding-top:25% from same
Bootstrap.css 4585
padding:0px
margin-bottom:16px; and your design will look as you expect. I have tested

Comment: ah ok, I can only go on what you've said in your question - so bare that in mind! If the remove padding makes a green border, then it sounds like you need to add another DIV element and have that contain a padding:0px for the border area, which the internal IMG element doesn't inherit. Should give you what you want (assuming Vipuls advice works)

Comment: use .text-center class in <p> element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to try to use as much of the bootstrap classes as possible, for example `.img-responsive` makes an image scale to the width of its container.

Create your own `.thumb` element that contains a `.thumb__image` for the image and a `.thumb__text` for the overlay text. The `.thumb_image` contains the image and uses normal positioning, the `.thumb__text` has `position: absolute` with all coordinates set to zero to make it as the image.

Inside the `.thumb__text` there is a `thumb__text-inner` that uses the vertical centering technique from css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ to center the text.

Make sure that all images have the same aspect ratio and that the text fits inside the dimensions of the image.

See the example below. I've added a negative margin of `-15px` to offset Bootstraps grid gutter which might be unwanted.

```css
.thumb {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -15px; // offsetting the grid
}

.thumb__text {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(39, 174, 96, .5);
  color: #fff;
}

.thumb__text-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.thumb:hover .thumb__text {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumb">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/400" class="img-responsive thumb__image" />
          <div class="thumb__text">
            <div class="thumb__text-inner">
              Omg! What a lovely kitten that is!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumb">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/800/400" class="img-responsive thumb__image" />
          <div class="thumb__text">
            <div class="thumb__text-inner">
              Omg! What a lovely kitten that is!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't add the lightbox to my example, only the part about the thumbnail and overlay text. Try to integrate my example with the code you already had. Next to that I noticed that one image (guy with a guitar) has a different aspect ratio (portrait instead of landscape). That doesn't look good. An option is to split the screen into three columns and put multiple images into each column stacking them vertically.

Answer (score 1):

[image: after removing <code>padding:0px !important</code> you will get like this]

Stylesheet.css line : 326 Remove `padding:0px !important` and then try whatever possible changes

also remove `padding-top:25%` from same
and 
Bootstrap.css 4585

```
padding:0px
margin-bottom:16px;
```

and your design will look as you expect. I have tested

Comment: Perhaps a fiddle would help DummerTroll? I see you've achieved it but I can't easily see how. But then, it's not my code...

Comment: I have changed the code as you said. Now I still have a fixed height on my anchor tags. How can I replace this? Also my text isn't vertical centered.

Comment: Instead of this CSS why not you are using .text-center class in <p> element?

Comment: @Hamza because he want text in vertical center in <a> tag and there is lots os style that prevent to use vertical-align middle.